# How to add DFU support to u-boot?

Tags: arm, usb, u-boot, dfu

I'm trying to add DFU support to the u-boot I'm using in my project because I figured out that DFU support is not enabled in it.

I'm using freescale u-boot (cloning from **git://git.freescale.com/imx/uboot-imx.git**) and I checked out the tag "**rel_imx_4.1.15_1.1.0_ga**" wich is the one I'm required to work on.

The thing is that going through the u-boot documentation I can see that DFU have to be enabled. I added the following to my .h file

```
#define CONFIG_USB_FUNCTION_DFU
#define CONFIG_CMD_DFU
#define CONFIG_DFU_MMC
#define CONFIG_SYS_DFU_DATA_BUF_SIZE SZ_16M
#define DFU_DEFAULT_POLL_TIMEOUT 300
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
common/built-in.o: In function `do_dfu':
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:29: undefined reference to `dfu_init_env_entities'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:35: undefined reference to `dfu_show_entities'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:41: undefined reference to `g_dnl_clear_detach'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:42: undefined reference to `g_dnl_register'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:44: undefined reference to `g_dnl_detach'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:50: undefined reference to `dfu_usb_get_reset'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:67: undefined reference to `usb_gadget_handle_interrupts'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:70: undefined reference to `g_dnl_unregister'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:72: undefined reference to `dfu_free_entities'
/home/m4l490n/uboot-imx/common/cmd_dfu.c:77: undefined reference to `g_dnl_clear_detach'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24 assertion fail ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:7696
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: error: required section '.rel.plt' not found in the linker script
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: final link failed: Invalid operation
make: *** [u-boot] Error 1
```

I noticed that If I remove **#define CONFIG_CMD_DFU** from the .h file it compiles fine but if I enter **=> dfu** in the u-boot shell it says:

```
Unknown command 'dfu' - try 'help'
```

So the question is *Do you know what else do I need to add to enable DFU in the u-boot I'm using?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. To fix these linking errors:

   > undefined reference to `dfu_*`

   enable the USB portion of the DFU USB class:

   ```c
   #define CONFIG_DFU_FUNCTION
   ```
2. To fix this linking error:

   > undefined reference to `usb_gadget_handle_interrupts`

   enable your UDC controller (I'm pretty sure your platform has ChipIdea UDC controller), and also enable USB gadget:

   ```c
   #define CONFIG_CI_UDC
   #define CONFIG_USBD_HS

   #define CONFIG_USB_GADGET
   #define CONFIG_USB_GADGET_DUALSPEED
   #define CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW 2
   ```
3. To fix these linking errors:

   > undefined reference to `g_dnl_*`

   enable and configure USB download gadget:

   ```c
   #define CONFIG_USBDOWNLOAD_GADGET
   #define CONFIG_G_DNL_VENDOR_NUM     0x18d1
   #define CONFIG_G_DNL_PRODUCT_NUM    0x0d02
   #define CONFIG_G_DNL_MANUFACTURER   "FSL"
   ```

Now you should be able to build U-Boot successfully. Tested on `configs/mx7dsabresd_defconfig` (with changes to `include/configs/mx7dsabresd.h`). Configuration values for download gadget (G_DNL) were taken from `include/configs/mx7dsabresdandroid.h`.

Basically, linking problems can be solved next way. To find out what definition is missing, you can look where missing function is implemented, then look for `Makefile` where corresponding source file is enabled for build, and from that `Makefile` you can figure out which option to define, so that corresponding object-file is built and wanted function is in place at linking stage.